# Android - detect type of Cast device

Tags: android, chromecast

Is there a way to somehow recognize a type of Cast device, to which my application is connected? (e.g. Chromecast, Nexus, Player, etc.)

I am using CastCompanionLibrary. The logic about connecting and disconnecting is in this library. In my fragment, in `onCreateOptionsMenu`, I have only this line of code:

```
mCastManager.addMediaRouteButton(menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item);
```

`mCastManager` is instance of class `VideoCastManager`. I would like to generally solution for my question.

First of all, is it possible to recognize the device?

Thanks for help.

**UPDATE**

The reason why I need to recognize the device is very simple. Everything is about MPD manifests. It exists more than one manifest type and we use `Time-Based Segment` manifest. With this manifest everything works fine on Chromecast for example.

However, there is a problem with this manifest on Nexus Player, because the seeking is broken on this type of device. So, I need to know the device type to inform user, that this is a chance that seeking will not work properly.
The `Segment-Base` manifest works fine with Nexus Player, but it is very time consuming to encode all of our video (`Time-Based Segment`) to `Segment Base` manifest.

Comment: How exactly is your application connected?  Could you post your code so that we have enough context to answer this question?

Comment: @EJK I have updated my question, but I think that there is no need to show more code, because I would like to know generally solution (if it does exist...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, we do not want to create an ecosystem where some apps run on one cast device and not on others. So my question for you is why you would need to recognize the type of device that you are running on? In those cases that devices are very different (for example a cast-enabled speaker vs Chromecast), we have "capabilities" apis to allow such differentiation.

Comment: Have you opened a bug for the issue that you are seeing on the Nexus player? You should look a that as a bug that needs to be addressed and (your) application shouldn't try to do any workaround for that issue. In terms of APIs, there is none to help you distinguish a Nexus player from a Chromecast.

Comment: Yes, I have opened an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=614&thanks=614&ts=1437057917

Comment: Ok, lets continue this thread over there; I  asked for some more info there.